# Two key shortcut in emacs without repressing the first key?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suppose I define the following shortcut

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-d C-j") "Hello!")`

Is it possible to configure emacs so that if I type `"C-d C-j C-j C-j"` I will get "Hello! Hello! Hello!" rather than having to type `"C-d C-j C-d C-j C-d C-j"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t think you can configure Emacs so that it does that for all commands. However, you can implement this functionality in the commands themselves. This is what is done for <kbd>C-x e</kbd>. **Here is a macro I just wrote** (guided by the standard definition of `kmacro-call-macro` in GNU Emacs 23.1.1) **that makes it easy to add this functionality to your own commands:**

```
(defmacro with-easy-repeat (&rest body)
  "Execute BODY and repeat while the user presses the last key."
  (declare (indent 0))
  `(let* ((repeat-key (and (> (length (this-single-command-keys)) 1)
                           last-input-event))
          (repeat-key-str (format-kbd-macro (vector repeat-key) nil)))
     ,@body
     (while repeat-key
       (message "(Type %s to repeat)" repeat-key-str)
       (let ((event (read-event)))
         (clear-this-command-keys t)
         (if (equal event repeat-key)
             (progn ,@body
                    (setq last-input-event nil))
           (setq repeat-key nil)
           (push last-input-event unread-command-events))))))
```

Here’s how you use it:

```
(defun hello-world ()
  (interactive)
  (with-easy-repeat
    (insert "Hello, World!\n")))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c x y z") 'hello-world)
```

Now you can type <kbd>C-c x y z z z</kbd> to insert `Hello, World!` three times.

Comment: See also the Emacs `repeat` package.

Comment: @event_jr Nice!! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DanielBrockman You gave a very good answer, but maybe instead of setting unread-command-events, push on it so other queued events don't get thrown out.  I'm not sure that's what would happen but that doesn't look right.

Comment: I wasn't gonna say anything, but ... why not make a macro that works just like defun, but repeatable?

Comment: @event_jr Oooh, yes. :) `defun-repeatable`? Seems kind of tricky to define a `defun`-like macro, though? You have docstring, `(interactive)` declaration, — anything else? Probably merits its own question, actually. I know, I’ll go create one! :D

Comment: I'll give it a shot if you create one.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for something generic that works on all commands I cant see how that would work - how would emacs know if you are starting a new command or want to repeat the previous. A better example would be "C-c h", if you type "h" after that, should emacs repeat the command or insert a h?

That said, emacs already has a mechanism for this - the universal argument.

Try this key sequence:

```
C-u 3 C-d C-j
```

It is even fewer keypresses than C-d C-j C-j C-j C-j

Comment: My toy example was probably too toy-ey. I'm trying to remap JKLI to be my navigation keys, so that `C-J` moves the cursor left, `C-L` right, `C-I` up, `C-K` down and so on. I would like to override this behavior so that if `d` is pressed then `C-J` deletes left, `C-L` deletes right, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") (lambda() 
                                  (interactive)
                                  (insert "Hello!")
                                  (message "Type j to print Hello!")
                                  (while (equal (read-event) ?j) 
                                    (insert "Hello!"))
                                  (push last-input-event unread-command-events)))
```

Idea taken from `kmacro-call-macro`

Comment: I suppose you should push back the last event which terminates the while loop, in order to not lose that keypress.  See Daniel Brockman's answer, although I otherwise like the crispness of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The *sequence* "ctrl-d ctrl-j" is what is bound to the string "Hello!" Emacs binds the sequence as a whole to the given string. Here's some good info on the topic:

[Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html)

On the other hand, if you *wanted* just three instances of "Hello!", you *could* define that sequence `C-d C-j C-d C-j C-d C-j` as "Hello! Hello! Hello!", but it would be shorter to just define a simpler sequence for the string you want.

Comment: What if I bind a function to `C-d` that binds "Hello!" to `C-j`. Then every additional time I press `C-j` I get "Hello!". Additionally I would need some way of listening for when the `d` key is released, so that I could unbind "Hello!" from `C-j`.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not just bind C-j to "Hello!" ?

Comment: Because I want something different to happen when I press `C-s C-j`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time.   You'll need library `repeat.el` (part of GNU Emacs) to use it.

```
    (defun make-repeatable (command)
      "Repeat COMMAND."
      (let ((repeat-message-function  'ignore))
        (setq last-repeatable-command  command)
        (repeat nil)))

    (defun my-hello ()
      "Single `hello'."
      (interactive)
      (insert "HELLO!"))

    (defun my-hello-repeat ()
      (interactive)
      (require 'repeat)
      (make-repeatable 'my-hello))
```

Now bind `my-hello-repeat`:

(global-set-key (kbd "") 'my-hello-repeat)

Now just hold down the <kbd>home</kbd> key to repeat *HELLO!*.

I use this same technique in multiple libraries, including [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), [thing-cmds](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/thing-cmds.el), and [wide-n](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/wide-n.el).

Answer (score 0):

[smartrep](https://github.com/myuhe/smartrep.el) is all you want

```
(require 'smartrep)

(defvar ctl-d-map (make-keymap))  ;; create C-d map
(define-key global-map "\C-d" ctl-d-map)


(smartrep-define-key
    global-map "C-d"
    '(("C-j" . (insert "hello"))))
```